# Shedlock dynamic lock name template interpolation

Tags: spring, templates, shedlock

I need to use method parameters as part of the lock name.

```
  @SchedulerLock(name = "my-job-#{tenantId}-#{date}")
  public void job(UUID tenantId, LocalDate date) {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an updated library the correct syntax is:

```
  @SchedulerLock(name = "my-job-#{#tenantId + '-' + #date}")
  public void job(UUID tenantId, LocalDate date) {

  }
```